# Is there a direct link to tag sets inside Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-filters

I really like the new tag sets feature. While I can see it is useful across many sites, I've set up a tag set that only targets Stack Overflow.

Is there any way I can view my tag set directly from Stack Overflow and thus have the same Stack Overflow "branding" (colors, etc.) applied? For example, https://stackoverflow.com/tagsets

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

We do link to tag sets now from the Interesting / Ignored widget, however, so there is a way to get there on almost every page.